# Hangfire Dashboard customization : display jobs list with queue name

Tags: c#, queue, customization, dashboard, hangfire

I'd like to customize Hangfire Dashboard to display the jobs list along with the queues they were, are, or will be enqueued in, and their status.
I haven't found any method in the IMonitoringApi interface doing that for multiple jobs, the closer I've been was :

1. with the **JobDetails** method of the IMonitoringApi : it gets a job along with its queue, but it does that for just one job, and I don't want to loop on it because it would generate too much requests.
2. with the **SucceededJobs, FailedJobs, and so on**, methods of the IMonitoringApi. They all return among other things jobs objets which contain a Method and details about it, among which the queue it's gonna be enqueued in. But the code isn't very robust, and it's kind of a twisted way to get something, when it should be pretty straightforward.
3. With the **EnqueuedJobs** method : it returns all the jobs within a specified queue, but as I understand it, if the job isn't "enqueued" anymore, it will be ignored.

So, for now, my guess is either I create my own implementation of the IMonitoringApi and add to it a method derived of the JobDetails method, or I try to get the Job's method's informations in a more robust way.

Is there anything I've missed ? What would be your way of doing it ?

Comment: You are willing to create a new page in the Hangfire Dashboard or a page of your own? Which jobs do you want to display? All jobs including finished and enqueued?

Comment: I'd like to create a new page in the Hangfire Dashboard. In the best case, I'd like to display all jobs, including finished and enqueued, with filter options such as the concerned queue and the job status, but as a first step, displaying all jobs should be fine.

Comment: Any more help on this? I am looking for a similar approach

Comment: @ClémentRieu: Can you please share details. How did you solve the issue?